# Modify a PHP (CLI) file without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, command-line-interface

I am using [Spatie's](https://github.com/spatie/twitter-streaming-api) Twitter Streaming API package in order to open a channel and receive tweets for particular hashtags, as they come in. This file (receiver.php) is run via CLI.

Is there any way to modify this file, without reloading it each time? (For example, if I wanted to add another hashtag to be tracked). Two solutions I can think of are :

- Storing these hashtags in MYSQL and accessing them each time
- Using Ajax to fetch from another php file that would echo a JSON

The MYSQL method is extremely resource intensive (Since I expect to process 50-100 tweets per second at max load), and I'm not sure if Ajax/JS can work when run from the CLI. Are one of these the right options? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Update : Here is the structure of receiver.php :

```
Set variables and open stream //Happens once at the start
if(data received)
{
Handle it here //ONLY this section runs when a tweet is received
}
```

Comment: You could have it just check MySQL every few minutes for an updated list of hashtags.

Comment: "The MYSQL method is extremely resource intensive," You could use memcache or a local tmp file cache and when it expires, fetch from the DB and re-cache.

Comment: Edited the question to make it a bit clearer. Checking Mysql every few minutes won't work since it will run every time a tweet is found @ceejayoz

Comment: @Scuzzy Thank you, I will try that and see if it fits the job!